# How to preserve current console row when other thread is printing

Tags: java, multithreading, console

Lets say you have 2 threads.

- One prints a message, lets say `foo`, to the console every 5 seconds. `System.out.println("foo")`
- The other reads input from the user. `bufferedReader.readLine()`
- Then lets say you are in the middle of writing when the first thread prints its message. How do i keep the text the text the user is currently typing, while still allowing the first threads message to be printed to the console?

**What is happening now:**

Typing:

```
>> foo
>> foo 
hello wor
```

Then the first thread prints its message:

```
>> foo
>> foo 
>> hello worfoo
```

**What i want to happen:**

Typing:

```
>> foo
>> foo 
hello wor
```

Then the first thread prints its message:

```
>> foo
>> foo 
>> foo
hello wor
```

How would i go about this?

I don't mind if the solution is a hack, this is only a proof of concept.

Comment: Perhaps write a `static synchronized` function that calls `System.out.println`, that way it can only be called by 1 piece of code at a time. Although be warned that any other code that uses `System.out.println` directly will mess up your output.

Comment: I think having the join() method be called after console write will wait for a first thread to print foo before writing to console?